# Property 'sendEmailVerification' does not exist on type 'Promise<User>'.ts(2339)

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have this error :

```
Property 'sendEmailVerification' does not exist on type 'Promise<User>'.ts(2339)
```

my code :

```
// Send email verfificaiton when new user sign up
  SendVerificationMail() {
    return this.afAuth.currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
    .then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['verify-email-address']);
    })
  }
```

I don't know the origin of the error and what am I missing?

Comment: It looks like `this.afAuth.currentUser` is a promise, not a User object.  You'll have to use await or then on it to get to the User.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to wait until the promise resolves:

```
  SendVerificationMail() {
    return this.afAuth.currentUser.then((user) => {
      return user.sendEmailVerification();
    }).then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['verify-email-address']);
    })
  }
```